# Preventing Regex backtrack for SI prefixes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I'm using regular expressions to capture SI units (and some non-SI units), and format them properly with a multiplication dot.

For example: "Js" becomes "J⋅s" and "mΩm" becomes "mΩ⋅m" etc.

The problem is, there are some prefixes that are also SI units (e.g. "m") and so what I've written will wrongly  convert "mΩ" to "m⋅Ω".

```
var $dot = "\u22c5";
var $minus = "\u2212";

var $prefix = "(p|n|\u00B5|m|c|d|k|M|G|T)";
var $si_unit = "(m|g|l|L|s|A|K|mol|cd|Hz|rad|sr|N|Pa|J|W|C|V|F|\u03A9|S|Wb|T|H|\u00B0C|\u00B0F|lm|lx|Bq|Gy|Sv|kat|eV|\u0025)";
var $power = "([+" + $minus + "]?\d+)";

var $unit = "(" + $prefix + "?" + $si_unit + $power + "?)";
var $multiplied = $unit + "(" + $dot + $unit + ")*";
var $denominator = $multiplied + "(\/" + $multiplied + ")?";

var $corrections= [
    {
        // corrects dot products
        pattern: new RegExp( $unit + "(?=" + $unit + ")", "g" ),
        correction: "$1" + $dot
    }
    // more correction patterns later
];

function correct( $string ) {

    var $corrected = $string;
    $corrections.forEach( function( corrector ) {
        $corrected = $corrected.replace( corrector.pattern, corrector.correction );
    });
    return $corrected;
}

correct( "m" ); // m - CORRECT
correct( "mΩ" ); // m⋅Ω - INCORRECT, should be mΩ
correct( "Ωm" ); // Ω⋅m - CORRECT
correct( "mΩm" ); // mΩ⋅m - CORRECT
```

**Update** as @nhahtdh pointed out, the problem is with the lookahead backtracking as it doesn't find a `$unit` after the Ω, so backtracks and identifies m and Ω as `$unit + $unit` instead of a `$prefix + $unit`.  I need to prevent backtracking in this case.

Comment: The problem is due to the look-ahead, which tries to match, but fail, and the match backtracks to m, where the look-ahead finds Ω.

Comment: I am a bit confused still, essentialy you want any prefix mixed with any SI unit to have a ⋅ appear after it? Essentialy the factor you look out for if there is already a dot after it if not create the dot no matter what situation (like mΩ is in a sentence "thismΩhouse" should become "thismΩ⋅house")

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have a unique solution for each case.

Where do you want the dot placed in for example mmΩ?
Should it be mm ⋅ Ω or should it be m ⋅ mΩ?
Both answers are valid in my opinion.

**Edit:**

Or if we look at a more ridiculous example: (nobody in their right mind would write it like this though)

mmmmol

We can split this in the following ways:

- m ⋅ m ⋅ m ⋅ mol = m^3 ⋅ mol
- m ⋅ m ⋅ mmol = m^2 ⋅ mmol
- m ⋅ mm ⋅ mol
- mm ⋅ mmol
- mm ⋅ m ⋅ mol

So unless you specify some assumptions you will probably not get every edge case exactly the way you want it.

**Edit 2:**

One way to prevent these inconsistencies is to enforce the guidelines as presented [here](http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP811/sec06.html) when people enter the units and show a warning when they make a mistake.

**Edit 3:**

If you want greedy behaviour, you will have to match for an endOfLine. Otherwise the last match isn't treated in a greedy way.

You also have to make sure that the units with the longest stringlength are at the front of your matches list. If you don't do this it wil match the **m** unit before **mol** and quit there, thus never reaching **mol**.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/61cLor1g/4/) jsfiddle for the code in action

```
var $dot = "\u22c5";
var $minus = "\u2212";

var $prefix = "(?:\u00B5|c|d|G|k|m|M|n|p|T)";
var $si_unit = "(?:kat|mol|rad|\u00B0C|\u00B0F|Bq|cd|eV|Gy|Hz|lm|lx|Pa|sr|Sv|Wb|\u0025|\u03A9|A|C|F|g|H|J|K|l|L|m|N|s|S|T|V|W)";
var $power = "(?:[+" + $minus + "]?\\d+)";

var $unit = "("+ $prefix + "?"+ $si_unit + $power + "?)";

var $multiplied = $unit + "(" + $dot + $unit + ")*";
var $denominator = $multiplied + "(\/" + $multiplied + ")?";

var $corrections= [
    {
        // corrects dot products
        pattern: new RegExp( $unit + "(?=($|" + $unit + "))", "g" ),
        correction: "$1" + $dot
    }
    // more correction patterns later
];

$(document).ready(function() {


    var resultsElem = $("#results");

    addToResults(resultsElem, correct( "m" )); // m - CORRECT
    addToResults(resultsElem, correct( "m\u03A9" )); // mΩ - CORRECT, should be mΩ
    addToResults(resultsElem, correct( "\u03A9m" )); // Ω⋅m - CORRECT
    addToResults(resultsElem, correct( "m\u03A9m" )); // mΩ⋅m - CORRECT
    addToResults(resultsElem, correct( "mmmmol" )); // mm⋅mmol - CORRECT
});

function correct( $string ) {

    var $corrected = $string;
    $corrections.forEach( function( corrector ) {
        $corrected = $corrected.replace( corrector.pattern, corrector.correction );
    });

    //if you want greedy behaviour, you will have to match for the end of the line too.
    //The replace function will put a dot at the end too. Remove it if it's there.
    if($corrected.charAt($corrected.length -1 ) == $dot){
        $corrected = $corrected.substring(0,$corrected.length -1);
    }
    return $corrected;
}

function addToResults(elem, theResult){
    elem.append(theResult).append("<br>");
}
```

Comment: It should be greedy, so in your example, **mmmmol** becomes **mm⋅mmol**.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:p|n|m){0,1}(?:m|g|l|L|s|A))((?:p|n|m){0,1}(?:m|g|l|L|s|A))
```

EDIT: Understood now a bit better what you wanted and i think this should work, each side of the prefix+unit (or only prefix) is saved in capture group 1 and 2

```
(?:p|n|m) being the prefixes
```

and

```
(?:m|g|l|L|s|A) being the units
```

For the adding of the dot you just itterate through the results and place the dot after each result

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that's much different from the original.
I tried to adapt to my code with
`var $unit = "((?:" + $prefix + ")?(?:" + $si_unit + ")" + $power + "?)";`
but the problem remains.
Did I adapt it wrongly perhaps?